# Does the SPECIAL max out at 10 or can I put clothes on to make it 10+?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have a 10 endurance dweller and I'm wondering if there's any point to put on my +5 endurance suit on him or does it max out at 10 no matter what? Thanks.

Comment: It might be a very bad thing that the answer to this question has supporting research and the linked question's answer says the opposite thing without support.  This one is probably the right answer, and we're sending people looking for this answer to the wrong answer.

Answer (score 2):

Points above 10 decrease room rushing incident risk percentage and increase room production speed.

[Source: REDDIT](http://www.reddit.com/r/foshelter/comments/3bj9o1/discovered_something_interesting_today_thoughts/)